# Spring concurrent processing multiple queues with single thread pool

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-integration

I have a spring application that should process and store a socket incoming data, because of bottle neck problems this should be done with multi threads.

Incoming data belongs to **many** entities and **each entity tasks should process serially**, but I think assigning a single thread to each entity is not a good solution (thousands of single threads to process each entity's queue)

So how can I define a public `ThreadPool` to process all entities's queues with a fare algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Project reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) or [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) to split incoming messages stream by groups and to process events in every group serially.

With Project Reactor your code can looks like:

```
    Scheduler groupScheduler = Schedulers.newParallel("groupByPool", 16);
    Flux.fromStream(incomingMessages()) // stream of new data from socket
            .groupBy(Message::getEntityId) // split incoming messages by groups, which should be processed serially
            .map(g -> g.publishOn(groupScheduler)) //create new publisher for groups of messages
            .subscribe( //create consumer for main stream
                    stream ->
                            stream.subscribe(this::processMessage) // create consumer for group stream and process messagaes
            );
```

Comment: in your example code , you are creating new Parallel thread pool for each group that i point it as a bad solution in my question.processing all tasks with a fare algorithm with a single thread pool is my target

Comment: @Mojtabye agree, sorry missed this. Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You've described a perfect problem to solve with a message-driven architecture.

Spring Integration is the module which provides this for you.

You can build your task services and annotate with @ServiceActivator and create your chain with Channels.

The channels can have options to execute on a different thread pool, and bottlenecks due to spike load can be overcome with queue settings on your channel.

Definitely worth a try to check out the documentation of Spring Integration.